# When I click "File" - "New", an error message will appear in my Android studio

Tags: android-studio

```java
com.fasterxml.aalto.WFCException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xff
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,2]
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.in.XmlScanner.reportInputProblem(XmlScanner.java:1333)
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.in.ByteBasedScanner.reportInvalidInitial(ByteBasedScanner.java:446)
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.in.Utf8Scanner.decodeCharForError(Utf8Scanner.java:2708)
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.in.StreamScanner.nextFromProlog(StreamScanner.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.aalto.stax.StreamReaderImpl.next(StreamReaderImpl.java:790)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.JSvgDocumentFactoryKt.buildDocument(JSvgDocumentFactory.kt:95)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.JSvgDocumentFactoryKt.createJSvgDocument(JSvgDocumentFactory.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.JSvgDocumentFactoryKt.createJSvgDocument$default(JSvgDocumentFactory.kt:34)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.JSvgDocumentFactoryKt.createJSvgDocument(JSvgDocumentFactory.kt:30)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.SvgKt.renderImage(svg.kt:291)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.SvgKt.renderAndCache-rdQnj48(svg.kt:261)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.SvgKt.access$renderAndCache-rdQnj48(svg.kt:1)
    at com.intellij.ui.svg.SvgKt.loadSvgAndCacheIfApplicable-F6nGey4(svg.kt:590)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.ImageCacheKt.doLoadByDescriptor(imageCache.kt:290)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.ImageCacheKt.loadByDescriptorWithoutCache(imageCache.kt:177)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.ImageCacheKt.loadImage(imageCache.kt:139)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.ImageDataByPathResourceLoader.loadImage(ImageDataByUrlLoader.kt:65)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.CachedImageIcon.loadImage$intellij_platform_util_ui(CachedImageIcon.kt:313)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.ScaledIconCache.getOrScaleIcon(ScaledIconCache.kt:43)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.CachedImageIcon.resolveActualIcon(CachedImageIcon.kt:158)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.CachedImageIcon.getIconWidth(CachedImageIcon.kt:119)
    at com.intellij.ui.icons.IconUtilKt.checkIconSize(iconUtil.kt:420)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.filterIcon(IconLoader.kt:330)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$getDisabledIcon$2.invoke(IconLoader.kt:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader$getDisabledIcon$2.invoke(IconLoader.kt:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getDisabledIcon$lambda$7(IconLoader.kt:279)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getDisabledIcon(IconLoader.kt:279)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getDisabledIcon(IconLoader.kt:267)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.updateIcon(ActionMenuItem.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.updateFromPresentation(ActionMenuItem.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.fillMenuInner(Utils.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.fillMenu(Utils.java:360)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.fillMenu(ActionMenu.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.setPopupMenuVisible(ActionMenu.java:390)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JPopupMenu.menuSelectionChanged(JPopupMenu.java:1506)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.MenuSelectionManager.setSelectedPath(MenuSelectionManager.java:134)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI.appendPath(BasicMenuUI.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicMenuUI.java:322)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:311)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:243)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:690)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:593)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithoutImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1485)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:593)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

Android Studio INFO

Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
Build #AI-232.10227.8.2321.11479570, built on February 22, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0--11185874 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.zone.unique.plugin.singleton (1.3)
Batch Scripts Support (1.0.13)
com.intellij.marketplace (232.10227.13)
wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4)
GsonOrXmlFormat (2.0)
idea.plugin.protoeditor (232.9559.10)
de.ohmesoftware.parcelablegenerator (0.7.1)
com.bytedance.tools.codelocator (2.0.1)
com.pingfangx.plugin.legacylayoutinspector (1.2.0)
com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.13)
mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore (4.5.2)

what's wrong? i can not new any files.

restart the Android studio is not work！

Comment: not sure this question belongs to stackoverflow, maybe you could ask it on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Disable plugins on startup